# pandas groupby two columns and generate columns from second

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like:

```
index col1   col2   col3   col4   col5
0     a      c      1      2      f 
1     a      c      1      2      f
2     a      d      1      2      f
3     b      d      1      2      g
4     b      e      1      2      g
5     b      e      1      2      g
```

if i group by two columns, like the following:

```
df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).agg({'col3':'sum','col4':'sum'})
```

I get:

```
           col3  col4
col1 col2            
a    c        2     4
     d        1     2
b    d        1     2
     e        2     4
```

Is it possible to convert this to:

```
col1 c_col3 d_col3 c_col4 d_col4 e_col3 e_col4
a    2      1      4      2      Nan    Nan
b    Nan    1      Nan    2      2      4
```

in an efficient manner where col1 is the index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) for `MultiIndex` in columns, so necessary flattening:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).agg({'col3':'sum','col4':'sum'}).unstack()
#python 3.6+
df1.columns = [f'{j}_{i}' for i, j in df1.columns]
#python bellow
#df1.columns = ['{}_{}'.format(j, i) for i, j in df1.columns]
print (df1)
      c_col3  d_col3  e_col3  c_col4  d_col4  e_col4
col1                                                
a        2.0     1.0     NaN     4.0     2.0     NaN
b        NaN     1.0     2.0     NaN     2.0     4.0
```

Comment: That was a crazy fast answer !!